# Unable to launch .bat

Tags: batch-file, launch

I have a Minecraft server; When you run the server for the first time, it starts generating the world you are going to play on in the folder where you have the Minecraft_server.exe (This is normal behavior.)

I made a batch to open the Minecraft_server.exe. But when I place the .bat on my desktop and run it, it starts creating new server files instead of starting the program in the original folder where the existing world is.

How can I launch the bat anywhere on the PC, such that it wont generate new folders? I want it to always start in the Minecraft server folder.

Comment: Could you post your .bat file? It might help in figuring out your problem.

Comment: start "" "C:\Users\pcname\Desktop\MinecraftServer\Minecraft_Server.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first switch to proper drive and then using **cd** command switch to Minecraft server folder. Then you can run .exe with absolute path (if it is not in Minecraft server folder).

Comment: thanks Lukas that helped resolve my problem